# Difference of <long>/<long> vs. <int>/<int>

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction, clang, compiler-optimization

When compiling the following code:

```
int f(int i1,int i2)
{
    long l1=i1;
    long l2=i2;
    return l1*l2;
}
```

with `clang 10.1` for `x86-64` and with `-O3`, I get

```
    mov     eax, edi
    imul    eax, esi
    ret
```

The compiler recognizes, that a full 64 bit operation is not needed.

However, when I replace the multiplication by a division:

```
int f(int i1,int i2)
{
    long l1=i1;
    long l2=i2;
    return l1/l2;
}
```

it compiles into

```
    movsx   rax, edi
    movsx   rsi, esi
    cqo
    idiv    rsi
    ret
```

So it uses a 64-bit division (same for gcc).

What is the counter-example which prevents to use a 32-bit division here?

Comment: The code gen [is better in LLVM 11](https://godbolt.org/z/y-MD3N) with a special case for 32-bit values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider what happens when `i1 == INT_MIN == -2147483648` and `i2 == -1`.

For comparison, let's also consider

```
int g(int i1, int i2) {
    return i1/i2;
}
```

which compiles to a simple 32-bit `idiv`.

If you call `g(INT_MIN, -1)`, the division will overflow, since the result `2147483648` doesn't fit in `int`.  This results in  undefined behavior at the level of C, and in fact the `idiv` instruction will generate an exception.

If you instead call `f(INT_MIN, -1)`, the division does not overflow, because the result does indeed fit in a `long`.  Now the `return` statement causes it to be converted to `int` by the usual integer conversions.  Since the value doesn't fit in the signed type `int`, the result is *implementation-defined*, and gcc [documents](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation) what it will do:

> The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a signed integer type when the value cannot be represented in an object of that type (C90 6.2.1.2, C99 and C11 6.3.1.3).
>
> For conversion to a type of width N, the value is reduced modulo 2^N to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.

So it needs to generate code that ensures that an exception is not generated, and that the value returned is `-2147483648` (which is equivalent to `2147483648` mod 2^32).  A 32-bit divide won't do it, but a 64-bit divide will.

Interestingly, icc [handles this](https://godbolt.org/z/0Mg-2z) by special-casing `i2 == -1` and doing a 64-bit divide only in that case, and a 32-bit divide otherwise.  This might be reasonable as it seems that 64-bit IDIV is potentially several times more expensive than 32-bit, glancing at Agner Fog's instruction tables.  Though you might wish it would use NEG instead of dividing in that case (and if you're wondering, yes, NEG of `INT_MIN` is `INT_MIN` as desired).

(Actually, the special casing of `-1` by icc was the hint that helped me realize the counterexample.)

No such special handling is needed for multiplication, because the behavior of `imul` on overflow is already what is needed for conversion: it truncates to 32 bits with no exception.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out! Actually, I tried several border cases and either I missed this one or tested wrong.

Comment: I believe the counter example for division by -1 instead of negation happens when you're not using two's complement arithmetic (although don't quote me on that). (Although I doubt this is a problem in practice.)

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso: But we're speaking of the implementation on a machine that *does* use two's complement arithmetic.  And even at the level of C, since `x / -1 == -x` is true mathematically, it has to hold for integer arithmetic whenever the result can be represented in the appropriate type.

Comment: @NateEldredge You're probably right, but I'm kind of interested in trying to figure out if it's truly an oversight by the compiler writers or if there's some edge case I've missed...